# Why jQuery.post sends not full object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I have an object `data` with some information. Then i add there some other info like this:

```
table_company.find('tr').each(function() {
    data['invoice_data'][this.id] = {
        'title': jQuery(this).find('td:eq(0) strong').text(),
        'value': jQuery(this).find('td:eq(1) input, textarea').val()
    };
});
```

The i send `data` via `jQuery.post` to the server. On the server appears only initial data, which was before `each` loop. I also printed the `data` object after the loot and all new info is in it, but it doesn't been transferred… Why?

UPDATE:

```
jQuery.post(
    ajax_url + 'saveInvoice',
    data,
    function(response) {}
)
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it called right after the each on the next line.

Comment: We may well also need more context on how and when `table_company` is initialized, and an example of the markup of the table. E.g., a [**small**, self-contained, complete example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Fundamentally, though, the answer is: Use the debugger built into your browser, set a breakpoint on the second line in the above and on the `post` call, and single-step through the code, watching it run and looking at the values as it goes.

Comment: That code all looks fine, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it not the first time when i face this bug… The main thing that i noticed that all data which is added  to the object by the indexes doesn't appear in `php` when sending via `jQuery.post`

Comment: The code that you have posted is correct. I think the problem is from the server side. Could you post your PHP code on [viper-7](http://viper-7.com/) and jQuery code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is :

You use **this.id** but in this case is undefined:

Try this method:

```
table_company.find('tr').each(function(i) {
    data['invoice_data'][i] = {
        'title': $(this).find('td:eq(0) strong').text(),
        'value': $(this).find('td:eq(1) input, textarea').val()
    };
});
```

Comment: *"You use this.id but in this case is undefined"* How do you know that? It's entirely possible that the OP has put an `id` on each row.

Comment: as i said, i printed the final object before send and there is all ok.